# How to switch PHP versions in Nginx if fastcgi_pass is pointing to a TCP socket

Tags: nginx, php

My question is simple (I hope).

Everywhere on the internet I read that if I want to change PHP versions in Nginx, I need to change the UNIX socket of the `fastcgi_pass` parameter. But my `fastcgi_pass` parameter is pointing to a TCP socket: `127.0.0.1:9250`. I've tried changing it to a UNIX socket, but that gave me a 502 Bad Gateway error, and I didn't know how to continue from there.

I'm currently running PHP 8.2, but I need PHP 8.1. I've installed it using `apt-get` and it's listed when doing `sudo update-alternatives --list php`. I tried the `sudo update-alternatives` approach, but that only changes the PHP version in CLI. Not FPM.

My nginx configuration is quite straight-forward:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
# master_process off;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/daan.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "~(?'project'([^.]+))\.dev.local$";
    return 301 https://$project.dev.local$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name "~(?'project'([^.]+))\.dev.local$";
    root "/etc/nginx/development/$project";

    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9250;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The listen parameter in `etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` points to the same TCP socket: `127.0.0.1:9250`.

**EDIT:** As requested, here's what I changed in `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. These edits are equal in `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

```
; Unix user/group of the child processes. This can be used only if the master
; process running user is root. It is set after the child process is created.
; The user and group can be specified either by their name or by their numeric
; IDs.
; Note: If the user is root, the executable needs to be started with
;       --allow-to-run-as-root option to work.
; Default Values: The user is set to master process running user by default.
;                 If the group is not set, the user's group is used.
user = daanvandenbergh
group = daanvandenbergh

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9250
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confused - there are at least 3 configurations (8.2 with network socket, 8.1 with network socket, 8.1 with network socket) only the nginx conf for one of the configurations and no details of HOW you changed the php-fpm config.

> I've tried changing it to a UNIX socket, but that gave me a 502 Bad Gateway error

You need the server to be listening in the place where the client is trying to connect. An additional complication with Unix domain sockets (compared with TCP sockets) is that it requires the file to have an owner and a group (typically the same owner as the uid the webserver runs as) e.g. in www.conf

```
listen = /var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

You also need to be *very* careful if you have two versions of PHP installed on the same host. I would ensure that the one you don't want has been completely removed before attempting to install the new one.

Unless you explicitly need a TCP socket, I'd suggest using the Unix domain socket. Although localhost is signifcantly faster than an address bound to a physical interface and has implicit security advantages, Unix sockets are faster still.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure I follow. I'm not seeing 3 configurations. I only have one at the moment: PHP 8.2 with TCP IP. I'm trying to get to 8.1. So, are you saying that the settings (user/group/listen) in www.conf should be equal to the settings in Nginx's conf (in my case, daan.conf)? Because that's the case. Except for the `user` at the top of the nginx.conf file, which is still www-data.

Comment: I explicitly listed the 3 configurations you described. What "user" in daan.conf? Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my question wasn't clear, I'm not a sysadmin, so it's not all as clear to me as it probably should. However, reading @symcbean's answer made it clear to me that switching to a UNIX socket shouldn't be the root of the problem -- which is what I assumed when writing my question. So, I just decided to go that route and deal with whatever came on my path.

Here's the edits I made to switch to another PHP version and as an added bonus, I figured out how to make it easy for me to switch between PHP versions in Nginx:

I changed the `fastcgi_pass` parameter in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/daan.conf` to `/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock`.

I changed the `listen` parameter in `/etc/php8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to the same value. I did the same for `/etc/php8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and `/etc/php8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Now, when running `sudo update-alternatives --config php`, the `php-fpm.sock` file becomes a symlink to the chosen PHP version, which PHP FPM and Nginx both listen to.

After that (and this part probably caused the Bad Gateway error I mentioned in my question earlier) it's important to properly restart Nginx and PHP-FPM (I copied and modified this script from [here](https://github.com/enflow/wsl2-php-development/tree/master#starting-up)):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/php
sudo service restart nginx
sudo service php(old version)-fpm stop -v
sudo service php(new version)-fpm start -v
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
sudo service mysql start
```

Now it works.